# Question about a certain topology in TVS presented in Edwards, Functional Analysis, and attributed to Bourbaki

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am having difficulty with a part of the following Lemma (Lemma 6.5.2 in Edwards, Functional Analysis, Theory and Applications). It might be trivial, now that I am writing this question.

Lemma. Let E be a TVS, $A$ a bounded, convex, balanced, sequentially
complete, and sequentially closed subset of E. Let $E_A$ be the vector subspace
of E generated by $A$.

$$E_A=\cup\{\lambda A , \lambda > 0\}$$

Let $p_A$ be the Minkowski functional for $A$.Then $p_A$ is a seminorm on $E_A$ (a norm if $E$ is separated) for which $E_A$ is complete. The topology on $E_A$ defined by $p_A$ is stronger than that induced on $E_A$ by the topology of $E$.

Proof: It is easily verified that $A$ is defined relative to $E_A$ by the equation
$p_A(x)\le 1$. A base of neighborhoods of $0$ for the topology defined by $p_A$ is formed
of the sets $\epsilon A$ $(\epsilon  > 0)$. This, together with the fact that $A$ is bounded in $E$, shows that the $p_A$-topology is stronger than that induced by the topology of $E$.
It shows also that $p_A$ is a norm on $E_A$ if $E$ is separated (Hausdorf).

The proof continues. But my difficulty is in the implication: The fact that $A$ is bounded in $E$ shows that the $p_A$-topology is stronger than that induced by the topology of $E$.

I want to show that the original topology on $E$ is contained in the new one defined by $p_A$.

I had the following thoughts:

1. Show that $A$ has a nonempty interior. Because it is sequentially complete, and an argument like the Baire Category Theorem proof might work. But $E$ is not metric or compact Hausdorf. I'm not sure this will even help... If that can be shown, then $A$ contains an original neighborhood of $0$, and $A-\partial A$ has a chance to be open.
2. Use that $A$ is absorbing to show that there is an open neighborhood in $A$.
3. Perhaps the set $\{x: p_A(x) < 1\}$ is open in the original topology? Then this set and its scaled versions generate the original topology. This actually makes the most sense. Is it that simple?

I am not sure what else to try. The proposed base for the $p_A$ topology doesn't seem qualified to generate the original topology.

Comment: The inclusion $E_A\to E$ is linear so that continuity is equivalent to continuity at $0$. Given an $E$-neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ boundedness of $A$ yields $\varepsilon>0$ with $\varepsilon A\subseteq U$ and since $\varepsilon A$ is an $E_A$-neighbourhood of $0$ this is the required continuity.

Comment: Definitely the answer I was searching for. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I believed I had answered my own question realizing that the Minkowski functional is continuous in the original topology.

However, this fails because not all open sets in $E$ are induced by $p_A$.